# first element not collapsing in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using collapse using bootstrap.I am trying to collapse first element  but its not working.Here's my code

```
<li class="c-bg-before-yellow list-group-item c-dropdown" style="font-size: 16px;font-weight:500;">
    <a class="analytics collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">AUDIT &amp; ASSURANCE</a>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
        <ul class="c-dropdown-menu c-content-list-1 c-theme  c-square listsss">
            <li class="c-bg-before-yellow">
                <a href="external_audits.php" class="">External Audits</a>
            </li>
            <li class="c-bg-before-yellow">
                <a href="internal_audits.php" class=" ">Internal Audits</a>
            </li>
            <li class="c-bg-before-yellow">
                <a href="rera_audits.php" class=" ">RERA Audits</a>
            </li>
            <li class="c-bg-before-yellow">
                <a href="agreed_upon_procedures.php" class=" ">Agreed Upon Procedures</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "first element is not collapsing? I have just tested your code,  and looks fine. https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/16724/

Comment: its not working did you check when the page load i need to expand first link content

Comment: by "first element" you mean the whole div element with id collapseExample? or the first link   "External Audits".Please update your question.What do you want to see as an output.

Answer (score 0):

By default, it will be auto-expanded.You need to use **accordion**.

```
<ul>
<li  class="accordion" id="accordion2">
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading"> <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2"
            href="#collapseOne">  
            AUDIT &amp; ASSURANCE
         </a> 
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
              <ul class="c-dropdown-menu c-content-list-1 c-theme  c-square listsss">
            <li class="c-bg-before-yellow">
                <a href="external_audits.php" class="">External Audits</a>
            </li>
            <li class="c-bg-before-yellow">
                <a href="internal_audits.php" class=" ">Internal Audits</a>
            </li>
            <li class="c-bg-before-yellow">
                <a href="rera_audits.php" class=" ">RERA Audits</a>
            </li>
            <li class="c-bg-before-yellow">
                <a href="agreed_upon_procedures.php" class=" ">Agreed Upon Procedures</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</<li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yYuRz/52/